# Incorrect output of wchar_t characters in console c++

Tags: c++, unicode, console, wchar-t

I try to print wchar_t characters by their integer index to console, but some of them displays like empty rectangles, while with some of them (Chinese characters for example) it works fine.

I have folowing code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <codecvt>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    wcout << L"Example 1: " << wchar_t(25500) << "\n";
    wcout << L"Example 2: " << wchar_t(831) << "\n";

    return 0;
};
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZvVf.png) is how it looks in console

I think it's something to do with console font (I'm using MS Gothic), but I don't know what

Comment: Not all fonts contains all the glyphs.  You can checkout the font you are using using the __Character Map__ utility (start > Windows accessories).

Comment: `conio.h` is not a standard header. Please tag your question accordingly

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks/fontsupport.htm i see no MS Gothic in that list.

Comment: @ÖöTiib i don't see there any fonts available in console too

Comment: What windows you use? Mine windows 10 command prompt/properties/font seems to have Consolas, Courier New and Liberation Mono among first picks.

Comment: @ÖöTiib i have these fonts also, but the programm don't work right with them (even Chinese characters are not displayed)